# Make div fixed only inside another scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the page with structure something like this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="other_stuff"></div>
</div>
```

Header is the header of the page.
Messages div is the place where I push messages. Sometimes it filled, sometimes it empty.
Sidebar is navigation menu. 
Content is a long scrollable div.
And other stuff is other stuff.

I need to make sidebar be fixed in the page on the left side when content are scrolled. But sidebar should never overlay messages and header. 
In other words, when I scroll down the page, header and messages are scrolled with content normally. But when I scroll up the page, sidebar should't overlay messages and header div's.

I've used CSS property `position: fixed;` for this but with this property sidebar overlays messages. How can I fix this with CSS and javascript/jQuery?

Comment: make a fiddle with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want the sidebar to be fixed starting from a particular point.

This can be achieved through the jQuery. There are many ways, at least 3 I know. Here is the pure jQuery version i use in the cases like that (if you don't want to embed other external JS libraries)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $fixed_id = $('#Mod128, #Mod190'); //classess or IDs of the modules you want to stick
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop()>254) //amount of pixels from the top of the viewport when the sticky styles applied
            {
                $fixed_id.css({position:"fixed", top:0, width:"18%"}); //sticky styles items when scroll to a particular place
            }
    });
});
```

Other ways of doing that are using other JS libraries, I know 2 of them:

1) [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

2) [stickyjs.com](http://stickyjs.com/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its good if you can make jsfiddle of it or else I think something like below code can help you.
Fix height of your header and messages and give margin to the sidebar with total height of you header and messages.

```
#header, #messages {
height:3em;
```

}
`.content #sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:3em;
    width:5em;
}`

```
.content #content,.content #other_stuff{
width:3em;
margin-left:5em;
```

}

Comment: also as a suggestion use classnames in CSS instead of using id's